# Execute multiple queries in a single statement using postgres and node js

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I need to execute insert and delete query in a single statement like this

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME) VALUES (1, 'Paul');DELETE FROM  COMPANY WHERE ID='12';
```

This is my node.js code for executing query

```
pg.connect(pgConString, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            callBack("DB connection failed. " + err, null);
            return;
        }
        var query = client.query({
            text: "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME) VALUES (1, 'Paul');DELETE FROM  COMPANY WHERE ID='12';"
            values: [1, "Poul1"],
            name: "insertQuery"
        });
        query.on("error", function (err) {
            callBack("DB insertion failed. Error Message: " + err, null);
            return;
        });

        query.on('end', function (result) {

            done();
            return;
        });
    });
```

I got error message like this

> error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

is it possible to execute multiple queries in postgresql database using node.js ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you got any error?

Comment: Try without prepared without prepared statement

Comment: You might want to look into using a Postgres FUNCTION. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
pg.connect(pgConString, function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) {
        callBack("DB connection failed. " + err, null);
        return;
    }
    client.query({
        text: "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME) VALUES (1, 'Paul');",
        values: [1, "Poul1"],
        name: "insertQuery"
    });

    client.query({
        text: "DELETE FROM  COMPANY WHERE ID='12';",
        name: "deleteQuery"
    });

    client.on("error", function (err) {
        callBack("DB insertion failed. Error Message: " + err, null);
        return;
    });


});
```

Comment: Be Warned: Because each query above is an asynchronous operation, you cannot count on them finishing in the order as written. If the flow doesn't need to be controlled, then it's fine. But if it does, control the flow with callbacks, promises or async/await. Examples in the [node-postgres docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries)

Comment: @DILP Given that queries on the same client (onnection) are queued by node-postgres, the order is actually guaranteed. But you'd still want to wait for them sequentially, that's true.

Answer (score 8):

Although there is an accepted answer, it's a bit obsolete. For now node-postgres handles multiple queries in one call and returns a neat little array to you, like:

```
const db.query('select 1; select 2; select 3;')
results.map(r => (r.rows[0]['?column?']))
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

There is also an alternative 'opinionated' library, called [pg-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise), which also accepts query chains in one call and works with `sql` files as well.

Comment: Because of your answer, I added one for `pg-promise` also :)

Comment: Note that the question uses parameters during the query. Would it also work with parameters without building the query first using something like `pg-format`

Comment: No, if you use parameters then you'll get an error `cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`

Comment: True. Also mentioned in @Jahir's earlier comment. Sendin' more statements at once AND using parameters probably means, that you should turn to user-defined functions or procedures. You could also create a single string from your statement chain with the parameters inserted (as suggested in other answers and comments), but there is a performance price, cause pg has to parse and plan again and again all the queries before every subsequent runs. (If they are separate parametrized queries or you have a backend function for them, it can plan just once and cache the plans for later)

Answer (score 4):

When using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)...

First, we declare our queries + values via a flexible [QueryFormat](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.QueryFormat) list:

```js
const queries = [
    {query: 'select * from products where price > $1', values: [12.5]},
    {query: 'select * from payments where amount < ${amount}', values: {amount}}
];
```

Then we create a single-query formatted string:

```js
const sql = pgp.helpers.concat(queries);
```

And then we execute it, and retrieve the result:

```js
const [products, payments] = await db.multi(sql);
```

See: [concat](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.concat), [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi).