# Node Postgres Multiple Queries

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a query:

```
const getRunsByProjectTable = {
  text: 'Select pvt(); Execute pvtstmt;'
} ;
```

```
const getRunsByProjectTable = (req, res) => {
    pool.query(queries.getRunsByProjectTable, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.status(200).json(results.rows);
    })
}
```

It does not return anything but on pgAdmin, I am getting the desired table. Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute multiple queries in a single statement using postgres and node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625360/execute-multiple-queries-in-a-single-statement-using-postgres-and-node-js)

Comment: For some reason, those solutions do not work for me.

Comment: it could be the second statement. i am guessing the first make the statement in a fucntion and the second executes it. It will be better to put both on an procedure and run the procedure.